# Files Upload issue

Tags: angular

Previously uploaded files again gets uploaded while adding new files.
First when I try to add files it gets uploaded, when I try to upload new files again it gets added with previously uploaded files.

```
for (let j = 0; j < this.analysisDetails.analytes[i].uploadObjs.length; j++) 
{ 
if (this.analysisDetails.analytes[i].uploadObjs[j].uploadType === uploadType) 
{ 
typefound = true; 
console.log('update object' , JSON.stringify(uploadObj) ); this.analysisDetails.analytes[i].uploadObjs[j].files .push(...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(uploadObj.files))); break; } }
```

---

Comment: Please show the code you are using to upload, sample uploaded files and results, and explain what you think should happen instead. Do you want to check for a duplicate and not allow upload if so? Based on what: file name, MD5 hash, something else?

Comment: for (let j = 0; j < this.analysisDetails.analytes[i].uploadObjs.length; j++) {
                        if (this.analysisDetails.analytes[i].uploadObjs[j].uploadType === uploadType) {
                            typefound = true;
                            console.log('update object' , JSON.stringify(uploadObj) );
                            this.analysisDetails.analytes[i].uploadObjs[j].files
                                .push(...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(uploadObj.files)));

                            break;
                        }
                    }

Comment: In uploadObjs.files there is already some file and when we push uploadobj.files thats added to uploadObjs.files.

Comment: So, how to reset the uploadObjs.files??

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that info, as comments are not a fitting place for essential and/or formatted data.

Comment: take a look at the  code!